# rails & libpq-dev nasty dependencies

Tags: package-management, postgresql, rails, rvm, kerberos

I don't know if this question belongs here, but I'll take a shot. Hi. I'm running ubuntu 11.10 dual-boot with windows vista on my machine. On Ubuntu, I've installed RVM, rails gem, & PostgreSQL (the postgres server, client, & other packages like libpq5, because I installed it via Software Center).

I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku, but seems like i need to install *pg* gem. I tried to install it, but got this error instead:

> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /home/pcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for pg_config... yes
>
> Using config values from
>   /usr/bin/pg_config
>
> You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for
>   building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a
>   client-side application. You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y
>   for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a
>   client-side application.
>
> checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb
>   failed ***

After searching google & stackoverflow for a while, many people said that libpq-dev has to be installed. I tried, via software center but fail do to unmet dependencies. I tried via apt-get, it said that I need libkrb5-dev and krb5-multidev. I tried `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev libkrb5-dev krb5-multidev`, and got this:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  krb5-multidev :
>
> Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1
>   is to be installed
>
> Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
>
> Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

But I already have libkrb5-3, libk5crypto3, and libgssapi-krb5-2 (all with version 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1) on my system! I think maybe the version needed is 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1. So, maybe I have to remove the 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 packages first. Do you think it's safe for me to remove it? I tried to remove one of them, but software center warns me that it will also remove postgres, openssl-client, smbclient, cups, and many other packages.

What should I do to resolve this? And, is pg gem really necessary to be installed on my local machine to create rails app with postgres as the dbms? Is there a way to "hand over" the responsibility to include pg gem to heroku instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real solution is, as correctly [pointed out by Amit Patel](https://askubuntu.com/a/182062/19765), to install `libpq-dev`

---

Here is a workaround if you were unable to setup pg at you development machine. You can use sqlite in your local machine and pg in Heroku. Here is what you should have in your Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And use this command for installing bundle to ignore production gems:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Please keep in mind that not having same environment in production and development machines is not recommended.

Comment: Yup, this is the correct answer. +1, I do this all the time now.

Comment: @jrg do you experience some problem by doing this? I ask because heroku says "it's not recommended".

Comment: Heroku doesn't recommend it because generally you want to have the same development env as the server - however, as long as you are using ActiveRecord or DataMapper and you're not writing raw SQL, you should be fine 99% of the time. :)

Comment: Thanks @jrg and Arash . Will definitely try that out. Also, if I do this, I have to change development section & production section in config/database.yml accordingly, don't I?

Comment: @PatrixCR nope, heroku will do that for you.

Comment: I had a small problem that something not working locally but working on Heroku. But it was easy to find out as I knew something is wrong with db. But if you let the gap between your development and production get bugger you will face more problems. :)

Comment: Using sqlite is workaround. What is the solution then?

Comment: No way would I ever use a completely different database for development purposes than I would in production.  SQLite3 and PostgreSQL are night and day, as far as databases are concerned.

Answer (score 33):

I got same issue today. I followed message *You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.*
So installed libpq-dev and bundle rails app again and the error disappeared.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
$ bundle install
```

Comment: This is a better solution if you want to mirror postgres on your development machine, worked for me.